# Find variable's memory address via Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, memory-management

I want something that seems simple, however I do not know if it is... By declaring two javascript variables in Chrome's console e.g.

```
var x=true;
var y=true;
```

**is it possible to see the memory address of these variables x,y** by taking a `HEAP SNAPSHOT`. If yes, how? I want to find out if primitive variables in Javascript **contain a reference or point directly to their data**. To explain the above a little bit more: since `x===y` I want to be sure if this comparison has to do with the real values of the variables or their reference addresses. I know the latter is right for the objects, I thought the former is right for primitive values. Am I right?

Comment: [ECMAScript 2015, 7.2.13 Strict Equality Comparison (===)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-strict-equality-comparison)

Comment: You shouldn't think in terms of memory locations in Javascript. Two objects are the same if they're *the same object*. Whether that's implemented as a check for memory locations or internal ids or whatever else is irrelevant and subject to change.